# Injecting Interceptor jar file to my spring boot projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a `jar` file to inject into any of my spring boot project for logging the request details.

I am able to do this in one of my project. You can see the code below.

How to create the `jar` out of it and how to inject into other projects?

```
@Component
public class Interceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Interceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // log.info("Inside prehandle");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        // log.info("Inside postHandle");

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        log.info("Inside afterCompletion");
        sendToLoggerApi(request, response);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Interceptor interceptor;

    @Override
    public   void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```